# Loop through all colors?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm working on an app in C# (Windows-Phone-7), and I'm trying to do something simple that has me stumped.

I want to cycle through each Color in Colors, and write out the Color name to a file (along with other stuff).

I have the simplest bit of code, which I know will not work, but I wrote to get started:

```
foreach (Color myColor in Colors)
{
}
```

Of course, this gives me the following syntax error:

'System.Windows.Media.Colors' is a 'type', but is used like a 'variable'.

Is there a way to do this?  It seems really simple!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this helper method to get a Dictionary of each Color's name/value pair.

```
public static Dictionary<string,object> GetStaticPropertyBag(Type t)
    {
        const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

        var map = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (var prop in t.GetProperties(flags))
        {
            map[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(null, null);
        }
        return map;
    }
```

Use is with:

```
var colors = GetStaticPropertyBag(typeof(Colors));

foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> colorPair in colors)
{
     Console.WriteLine(colorPair.Key);
     Color color = (Color) colorPair.Value;
}
```

Credit for the helper method goes to 
[How can I get the name of a C# static class property using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536228/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-a-c-static-class-property-using-reflection/3536258#3536258)

Comment: That piece of code is AWESOME, and worked PERFECTLY!  Good show, perfect solution!

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28VS.95%29.aspx) to get all of the properties within the Colors type:

```
var colorProperties = Colors.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
var colors = colorProperties.Select(prop => (Color)prop.GetValue(null, null));
foreach(Color myColor in colors)
{
    // ....
```

Comment: Maybe you should add a Where-clause to the end of your GetProperties (just in case), something like: `.GetProperties(...).Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(Color))` or something like that?

Comment: @Alxandr: This is safe as it is - no need for the extra check (in this case).  All public properties of Colors are already of type Color.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors(VS.95).aspx

Comment: Ok, no prob then :-). Just remembering having something like that wrong once :-)

Comment: @Alxandr: Yeah - if it wasn't this specific case, it could be important.

Comment: Then you'd drop the casting in the select, and append the OfType? I've never used that one before.

Comment: @Alxandr: Yeah - you could do it that way.  It's a LINQ-based filter by type.

Comment: This *seems* good, but when I try to use it (in WP7 at least), the Colors word gives me the following compiler error:  An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property

Answer (score 2):

Well you can do so by using this code.

```
     List<string> colors = new List<string>();

    foreach (string colorName in Enum.GetNames(typeof(KnownColor)))
    {
        //cast the colorName into a KnownColor
        KnownColor knownColor = (KnownColor)Enum.Parse(typeof(KnownColor), colorName);
        //check if the knownColor variable is a System color
        if (knownColor > KnownColor.Transparent)
        {
            //add it to our list
            colors.Add(colorName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is Silverlight - System.Windows.Media.Color doesn't support KnownColors (that's System.Drawing).