# C# Looping through Colors?

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, colors

In my program, I need to cycle through the Known user colors available in order so it looks smooth and natural, like the DWM color slider.

The colors have to be converted to a uint aswell

```
private static uint ColorToBgra(Color     
{
   return (uint)
   (color.B | (color.G << 8) | (color.R << 16) | (color.A << 24));
}
```

Then set it. I tried setting it to white which uint is 0 then adding +1 every 0.1 seconds, but it isn't smooth and at intervals of about uint 250 it'll turn black then proceed.
Would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834659/c-sharp-loop-through-all-colors) work for me?I tried it but it doesn't.

Any ideas?

Comment: your code is making my eyes bleed.

Comment: BTW, `Color.ToArgb()` does the same as the `ColorToBgra()` method above.

Comment: Where did you find this code? I thought the `Blue` color should be right-shifted from the `color.B`. As far as I know the order of color elements is `B G R A` not `A R G B` as many think.

Comment: You should let us know how the `DWM color slider` looks so that we may have another approach.

Comment: Here is where all the code is :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/17808712/2609115

Comment: @MatthewWatson But does it return a uint ? :)

Comment: @Trontor No, but you can just cast the return value to `uint`.

Answer (score 2):

This might push you in the right direction?

```
// w goes from 0 to 100
private static Color spectrumColor(int w)
{
  float r = 0.0f;
  float g = 0.0f;
  float b = 0.0f;

  w = w % 100;

  if (w < 17) {
    r = -(w - 17.0f) / 17.0f;
    b = 1.0f;
  } else if (w < 33) {
    g = (w - 17.0f) / (33.0f - 17.0f);
    b = 1.0f;
  } else if (w < 50) {
    g = 1.0f;
    b = -(w - 50.0f) / (50.0f - 33.0f);
  } else if (w < 67) {
    r = (w - 50.0f) / (67.0f - 50.0f);
    g = 1.0f;
  } else if (w < 83) {
    r = 1.0f;
    g = -(w - 83.0f) / (83.0f - 67.0f);
  } else {
    r = 1.0f;
    b = (w - 83.0f) / (100.0f - 83.0f);
  }

  return Color.FromArgb((int)r * 255, (int)g * 255, (int)b * 255);
}
```

Comment: I'm quite new to programming and I have no idea how to implement this into my program, any help?

Comment: I have edited my answer so it works with System.Drawing.Color instead of XNA's Color.

Comment: what this algorithm is based on? what if i want max w to be 200?