# Get name of static property in static class with LINQ (expression)?

Tags: c#, linq, properties, static

Please see the code below. I want to create a Unit Test and use intellisense (for refactoring and compile time error purposes) to get me the name of a static property in a static class. I want this because I am loading an assembly from a file later on and need to get the value of a static property in a static class using reflection.

I know how it could be done using LINQ, see the `Hat` class below. But how would I get the `LastWashed` property of the `Underwear` class in a similar matter?

```
public class Test
{
    public static void TestFunction()
    {
        String NameOfColorPropertyOfHat = Hat.GetPropertyName(H => H.color);

        //How would I get the name of the property of the static class
    }
}

public static class Underwear
{
    public static DateTime LastWashed
    {
        get
        {
            return DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(3));
        }
    }
}

public class Hat
{
    public Color color
    {
        get
        {
            return Color.Green;
        }
    }

    public static string GetPropertyName(Expression<Func<Hat, object>> expression)
    {
        if (expression.Body is MemberExpression)
        {
            return ((MemberExpression)expression.Body).Member.Name;
        }
        else
        {
            var op = ((UnaryExpression)expression.Body).Operand;
            return ((MemberExpression)op).Member.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any LINQ in your code.

Comment: @ken2k I think OP means the use of expressions

Comment: Never mind, found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536228/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-a-c-sharp-static-class-property-using-reflection?rq=1
Searching for it for almost an hour now... I must be tired.